# Solving $\sin x - \cos x = 1$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I have been trying to solve $\sin x - \cos x = 1$ by squaring both sides but has not been able to obtain the solution. Here is what I did:

$$\begin{align}(\sin x - \cos x)^2 &=1^2\\\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x&=1\\1-\sin 2x&=1\\\sin2x&=0\end{align}$$

Obviously $x=0$ is not a solution. May I ask why this is the case or where did things go wrong?

Thank You

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618192/how-to-solve-sin-x-cos-x-1/618430#618430

Comment: When you square both sides you can get few "extra" answers. If you look on the second expression you'll see that $(\sin 0-\cos0)^2=1$, so if you square an equation the set of answers you'll get is superset of what you are looking for, i.e. it can contain values that won't solve the original equation

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots

Comment: I don’t feel that this question deserves to have been down-voted (as it currently stands at least). There is clearly some effort put in, and the OP is not asking for a straight answer but rather for guidance about the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that : $$\sin x - \cos x = \sqrt2 \sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$$ In this case, $$\sin x - \cos x = \sqrt2 \sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})=1 \implies \sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

Thus, two possible solutions are:

- $$x - \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4} \implies x = \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \, ,k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
- $$x -\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{3\pi}{4} \implies x = \pi + 2k\pi \, , k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: or $\sin x-\cos x=-\sqrt2\cos\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 7):

Use the property that $$\sin(x-y)=\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y$$

We can rewrite the left side of the equation....

$$\begin{align}\sin x-\cos x&=1\\\sqrt 2\left(\sin x\cos\dfrac\pi4-\cos x\sin\dfrac\pi4\right)&=1\\\sin\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)&=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\\x-\dfrac\pi4&=\dfrac\pi4+2k\pi,\pi-\dfrac\pi4+2k\pi\\x&=\boxed{\dfrac\pi2+2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi}\end{align}$$

Don't square both sides, it creates **extraneous solutions**

If you want, you can also use this property to start the solution....

$$\begin{align}a\cos x+b\sin x&\equiv R\cos(x-\alpha)\\\text{where }R=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},&\qquad\alpha=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac ba\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can not use squaring because $a=b$ is not equal to $a^2=b^2$.

After squaring you obtain also solutions of the following equations.
$$\sin{x}-\cos{x}=-1,$$ which we don't want.

I think it's better the following way.
 $$2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}-2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}=0$$ or
$$\cos\frac{x}{2}(\sin\frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2})=0,$$ which gives
$x=\pi+2\pi k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$ or $$\tan\frac{x}{2}=1,$$ which gives
$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k$.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you know the expansion$$\sin(\theta+\varphi)=\sin\theta\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi\cos\theta$$Because we can use it in the equation and greatly simplify the algebra needed. Rewriting your equation$$\sin x-\cos x=1\quad\implies\quad\sqrt2\left(\frac {\sin x}{\sqrt2}-\frac {\cos x}{\sqrt2}\right)=1$$The expression inside the parenthesis can be rewritten as$$\sin x\cos\frac {\pi}4-\cos x\sin\frac {\pi}4=\sin\left(x-\frac {\pi}4\right)$$Hence$$\sqrt2\sin\left(x-\frac {\pi}4\right)=1$$Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

After squaring both sides of the equarion, we get
$$
1=\sin^2x+\cos^2x-2\sin x\cos x=1-\sin2x.
$$
Hence
$$
\sin 2x=0
$$
i.e.
$$
x=x_k=\frac{\pi}{2}k, \qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Checking with the original equation, we have:

If $k=2n$, then
$$
\sin(x_{2n})-\cos(x_{2n})=(-1)^n
$$
If $k=2n+1$, then
$$
\sin(x_{2n+1})-\cos(x_{2n+1})=(-1)^n
$$
Hence, the solutions are 
$$
x_{4n}=2\pi n, \quad x_{4n+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n, \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a:= \sin x -\cos x;$ $ b=1;$

You have $a = b.$

Squaring: $a^2 =b^2$ gives

$(a-b)(a+b)=0. $

You find solutions for the squared equation:

$a=b$, or $a = -b.$

Need to be a bit careful:

$\sin 2x =0;$ or $x=0;$ implies:

1) $x = 2πk$, $k$ integer.

These are the solutions for $a = -b.$, I.e.

$\sin x - \cos x = -1$.

The solution to the original problem,

$\sin x - \cos x= +1:$

2) $2x = π$ ; or $x = π/2; $ or

$x = π/2 + 2πk.$

Answer (score 0):

As squaring will yield more answers than enough, I am now going to solve the equation using $\sin ^{2} x+\cos ^{2} x=1$.

Let $a=\sin x \text { and } b=\cos x,$ then

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a-b=1 \quad \cdots(1) \\
a^{2}+b^{2}=1 \quad \cdots(2)
\end{array}\right.\\
\Rightarrow \quad & a^{2}+(a-1)^{2}=1 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & 2 a(a-1)=0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & a=0 \text { or } 1
\end{aligned}
$$

A. When $a=0, b=-1$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\sin x=0 \\
\cos x=-1
\end{array} \Rightarrow x=(2 n+1) \pi\right. \text {, where }n\in Z.
$$
B. When $a=1, b=0$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\sin x=1 \\
\cos x=0
\end{array} \quad \Rightarrow x=\frac{(4 n+1) \pi}{2} \text {, where } n \in \mathbb{Z}\right.
$$
Therefore the solutions are $x=(2 n+1) \pi \text{ and } \dfrac{(4 n+1) \pi}{2}, \text {where } n\in Z.$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin x-\cos x &=1 \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos x &=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\cos \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) &=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
x+\frac{\pi}{4} &=2 n \pi \pm \frac{3 \pi}{4} \\
x &=\frac{\pi}{2}(4 n+1) \text { or }(2 n-1) \pi, \text{ where }n\in Z.
\end{aligned}
$$