# Solving $\sin(x)-\cos(x)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

Solving 
$$\sin(x)-\cos(x)=1$$
for $x$. I used Pythagoras' Theoream and 
$$C\sin(x+\alpha)=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$$
where $A=1$ and $B=-1$, and I obtained 
$$C=\sqrt{2}$$
$$\alpha = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$
and substituted where,
$$\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\dfrac{\pi}{4})=1$$
but somehow I think there is something wrong with my calculation, because in Wolfram it is
$$-\sqrt{2} \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-x)=1$$
and I don't understand why do I get a different solution, I did everything correct algebraically.

Comment: There are multiple solutions.  $x=\pi/2+2k\pi, \pi+2k \pi$

Comment: I don't think you did everything correct algebraically, because it should have been $-\frac\pi4$ instead of $\frac\pi4$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Is it wrong to use Pythagoras' Theoream, because I get $\sin(\alpha)=\dfrac{A}{\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos(\alpha)=\dfrac{B}{\sqrt{2}}= \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and now doing it again in my calculator I get that $\alpha= \dfrac{3\pi}{4}$

Comment: I can't really follow your logic, in the sense that you are referencing your own notation in your own sheet of paper some hundreds miles away from where I am, but the formula you should keep in mind appears to be $\sin(x+\alpha)=\cos\alpha\sin x+\sin\alpha\cos x$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618192/how-to-solve-sin-x-cos-x-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use the substitution $$\cos(x)=(\pm)\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$$ to obtain $$\sin(x)-\cos(x)=1\iff\ldots\iff \sin(x)-1=(\pm)\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$$
Squaring $$\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)+1=1-\sin^2(x)\iff 2\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)=0\iff \color{blue}{\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)=0}$$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Well, I set $v=\sin(x)$ and then wrote $2v^{2}-2v=0$ and solved for $v$ where I would get $v=0,1$ and so, $\sin(x)=1$ and $\sin(x)=0$, I will get $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$ and $x=\pi + 2\pi n$

Comment: Exactly @D. Qa ;)

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake:

$$
\sin x - \cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x\color{red}-\frac\pi4\right).
$$

The correctness of the last expression can be easily verified by trigonometric summation formula:

$$
\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y+\cos x \sin y.
$$

Comment: I am now confused, because when using Pythagoras' Theoream, you get $\sin(\alpha)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos(\alpha)=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and so $\alpha=-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ would be correct for sine but not for cosine because the value in cosine is negative, since $B=-1$

Comment: Well, checking again, $\cos(-\dfrac{\pi}{4}) \neq \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sin(-\dfrac{\pi}{4}) \neq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @D.Qa I have added the formula for the sine of a sum. Just substitute $y=\pm\frac\pi4$ and compare the results.

Comment: @D.Qa $$\begin{align}
\sin(x\color{red}+\frac\pi4)&=\sin x \cos\left(+\frac\pi4\right)+\cos x \sin \left(+\frac\pi4\right)=\frac{\sin x\color{red}+\cos x}{\sqrt2}\\
\sin(x\color{red}-\frac\pi4)&=\sin x \cos\left(-\frac\pi4\right)+\cos x \sin \left(-\frac\pi4\right)=\frac{\sin x\color{red}-\cos x}{\sqrt2}\end{align}
$$ Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Yes, I was trying it on my own, and it did actually, thank you, I think now I understood what is going on. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you're good.

Remember that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$.

That means that $-\sqrt{2} \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-x)$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{2} \sin(x-\dfrac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: The OP came up with $\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac]pi4\right),$ not $\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x-\frac]pi4\right).$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the so-called Weierstrass substitution:
$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

One thing you *could* do is square both sides. This yields $$\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x=1\\1-2\sin x\cos x=1\\\sin x\cos x=0\\\sin x=0\text{ or }\cos x=0.$$ This provides us with all integer multiples of $\frac\pi2$ as possible solutions. However, we must be a bit wary, since some of these may actually be solutions to $$\sin x-\cos x=-1.$$ Fortunately, periodicity means that we only have to check $0,\frac\pi2,\pi,\frac{3\pi}2$ to see which of those works, then conclude the rest accordingly.