# If $\sin x + \cos x =1+\sin x \cos x$, then find the general solution for x

Tags: trigonometry

Squaring on both sides 
$$\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x + 2\sin x \cos x=1+\sin^2 x \cos^2 x +2\sin x \cos x$$
$$\sin^2 x\cos^2 x=0$$
$$\sin 2x=0$$

I feel this answer is wrong because the answer is $n\pi + (-1)^n\pi /2$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid squaring as it immediately introduces [When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

Your solution includes $$\sin x+\cos x=-(1+\sin x\cos x)$$ as well

Use $$a+b=1+ab\iff(1-a)(1-b)=0$$

Comment: If that’s the case, then $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ will simultaneously be 1, which isn’t possible

Comment: @Aditya, if $$p\cdot q=0,$$ what can we conclude?

Comment: Assuming a and b are $sin x $ and $cos x$, $ab=0$ should be that $x=\pi , 0, \pi/2$

Comment: @Aditya, We need $$1-\sin x=0$$ or $$1-\cos x=0$$ right? Why are you saying simultaneously $$1$$

Comment: Then the answer could be $n\pi+(-1)^n\pi /2$ or $(2m+1)\pi /2$ but only the former is the right answer, according to the book.

Comment: @Aditya, $$\cos x=1,x=2m\pi$$ right? Check if that satisfies the given equation

Comment: Okay I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid [When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

set $$\sin x+\cos x=u,u^2=?$$

$$2u=2+u^2-1\implies(u-1)^2=?$$

Use [How to solve $\sin x +\cos x = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618192/how-to-solve-sin-x-cos-x-1)